# How does Safari name the 'Apple Touch Icon' files?

Tags: mac, safari, graphics

The touch icon files used in Safari are stored on a mac in the folder ~/Library/Safari/Touch Icons, and each file in a .png file, with what seems to be an arbitrary name.

By swapping an image in this folder, I can change the image displayed in Safari in the bookmarks bar.  However, I can't do the same for the bookmarks without an image already in the folder.

Does anyone know how Safari names these files, and how it connects a bookmark to this image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PNG files are named using a MD5 hash of the website URL. For example, the name for the Google image is stored by hashing `www.google.com` to get 0A137B375CC3881A70E186CE2172C8D1.png

Answer (score 1):

If you bookmark a page that shows an icon for it under the Bookmarks menu, it (the image) is stored in the *~/Library/Safari/WebpageIcons.db* file, which is an SQLite version 3 database. Images stored within the database can be in different formats, e.g. .ico, .png, etc.

If you really want to change the icon, that's in the database, I've done it with [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org).